# AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync() always returns null when using OAuth2 with MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-oauth

I've used VS2015 to used the MVC5 template to create a project. I'm using http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on as my example. It's all setup exactly as it should, but when `AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync()` always returns null.

The same basic setup works for facebook.

I'm not behind a firewall. I get to the google login page, I login, I get the authorize permissions, then back to the login page.

In Fiddler, I get a 401, followed by an entry that says

> /Account/ExternalLoginCallback?error=access_denied.

Comment: I don't have access to that link.. But it is worth looking at (http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/) and this (https://github.com/tjoudeh/AngularJSAuthentication). You may get solution.

Comment: are you sure you Set the Authorized redirect URI : https://localhost:[your-project-port]/signin-google in the Google Dev Console ?

Comment: @jeff i implemented Oauth2 in my project can u tell me how u are approached ..

Comment: Eslam - I did set the authorized redirect URI. Exactly how you say.

Comment: Webruster - I used the simplest possible thing. Visual Studio 2015 and the standard mvc5 template with individual user accounts. It's as vanilla as can be, yet it doesn't work for google.

Comment: Confirm  the Google ClientId and ClientSecret are correct (no spaces at beginning or end).